# Storing Dictionary in NSUserDefaults causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

```
//Declarations
var scoreIncrement:Int = 0
var team = ""
var userScore = Dictionary<String,Int>()

//Set Values
team = "USA"
userScore[team] = 0

//Store in NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userScore, forKey: "userScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

//Increment Score
scoreIncrement = 1
userScore[team]! += scoreIncrement
```

Above code gives 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)' error on last line of the code. However if I comment out line:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userScore, forKey: "userScore")
```

The error goes away. Any idea why this is happening, I am not even retrieving the dictionary from NSUserDefaults yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by retrieving the dictionary back out of NSUserDefaults right after saving it with:

```
var userScoreTemp : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userScore")
    if userScoreTemp != nil {
        userScore = userScoreTemp! as Dictionary
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. It turned out to be a KVO issue. It's possible that you have deallocated an object that was *observing* this value and so the message was being sent and not being received as it expects to be.

My solution was to remove the observer from the associated deallocated object. Always remember if you `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` to match it with an associating `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` call.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I stored String value in NSUserDefaults  like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stValue:@"Rahul" forKey:@"Name"];
```

After a certain period it crashed at the same point, writing the same value. The cause was that after this period I registered for changes in the NSUserdefaults with code like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(valueChange) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

This was done in an importer at initialization. After the importer was deallocaed, a new write to the user defaults was triggering the observer for an object that was gone. Crash.

The solution was of course to remove the observer .

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"Name"];